# take mean of data within the same day pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe `df` containing date of a measurement and the measurements (`duration`, `km`)

```
df
Out[20]: 
                          Date duration km
0   2015-03-28 09:07:00.800001    0      0
1   2015-03-28 09:36:01.819998    1      2
2   2015-03-30 09:36:06.839997    1      3
3   2015-03-30 09:37:27.659997    nan    5
4   2015-04-22 09:51:40.440003    3      7
5   2015-04-23 10:15:25.080002    0      nan
```

How can I calculate the average duration and km per day? I would like to take the mean of the rows using groupby and the date...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you need [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['Date'])
#if possible convert to float
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(float)
```

---

```
#if astype failed, because non numeric data, convert them to NaNs
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

#if mixed dtypes
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(str).astype(float)
#alternatively 
#df[cols] = df[cols].astype(str).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

---

```
df = df.resample('d', on='Date').mean().dropna(how='all')
print (df)
            duration   km
Date                     
2015-03-28       0.5  1.0
2015-03-30       1.5  4.0
2015-04-22       3.0  7.0
2015-04-23       0.0  0.0
```

Or:

```
df = df.set_index('Date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='d')).mean().dropna(how='all')
print (df)
            duration   km
Date                     
2015-03-28       0.5  1.0
2015-03-30       1.5  4.0
2015-04-22       3.0  7.0
2015-04-23       0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
what does exactly the last part .dropna(how='all') does?

Comment: There is problem resample return all missing values for consecutive datetimeindex. If some date is missing, value is added and filled by `NaN`s. [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) remove all rows with all `NaN`s. `John Galt` answer it dont need, but there is no datetimeindex, only index filled by python dates (maybe problem , maybe not)

Comment: I ve edited my question inserting some nans... is it possible to use nanmean?

Comment: There can be problem if all row(s) are `NaN`s, else solution works perfectly.

Comment: yes, exactly. in pandas mean working like nanmean - omit nans.

Comment: Hi, can you help me further? if I need to add a condition to take the mean, ie I want to compute different 2 different means, one for rows with duration <1 and the other for duration >=1 where should I put this condition in the groupby?

Comment: Unfortunately now I am on vacation, on phone only. So better is create new question. Thanks.

Comment: have nice holidays! :)

Comment: It's not necessary to use .set_index('Date'). Instead you can use key='Date' parameter within pd.Grouper(). df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='d')).mean().dropna(how='all').reset_index()

Answer (score 5):

Using `groupby`

```
In [896]: df.groupby(df.Date.dt.date).mean()
Out[896]:
            duration   km
Date
2015-03-28       0.5  1.0
2015-03-30       1.5  4.0
2015-04-22       3.0  7.0
2015-04-23       0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Thanks! however I get DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: Your `km` and `duration` columns are of string type perhaps?

Comment: it is  numpy.float64

Comment: Try `df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).groupby(df.Date.dt.date).mean()`?